# What is the difference between libboost-XXX-dev and libboost-XXX?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, debian, apt-get

Now I'm trying to use libboost-regex in my project. But I'm a little confusing because there are some relative libraries like below. I just want to use boost-regex. So in that case, what's the best way to install libboost-regex? And what's the difference between XXX-dev and XXX (without dev suffix)?

I assume XXX-dev library contains source file, on the other hand, XXX (without dev) doesn't contain source file, only .so or .a. Is my understanding right?

My environment is here.

```
ubuntu 12.04
gcc 4.8.2
```

And result of searching boost.

```
$aptitude search boost 
libboost-regex-dev                                 - regular expression library for C++ (default version)
libboost-regex-dev:i386                            - regular expression library for C++ (default version)
libboost-regex1.54-dev                             - regular expression library for C++
libboost-regex1.54-dev:i386                        - regular expression library for C++
libboost-regex1.54.0                               - regular expression library for C++
libboost-regex1.54.0:i386                          - regular expression library for C++
libboost-regex1.55-dev                             - regular expression library for C++
libboost-regex1.55-dev:i386                        - regular expression library for C++
libboost-regex1.55.0                               - regular expression library for C++
libboost-regex1.55.0:i386                          - regular expression library for C++
```

Comment: Since the name of packages depends on your package manager, I would say that you should write the name of your system or package manager in the question. But I think most or all package managers use dev-suffix the same way.

Comment: Sorry, I added my environment information.

Answer (score 5):

dev provides the development headers. that's needed if you want to compile things that use boost, rather than just run programs that link dynamically with boost

the version numbers are exactly that, different versions of boost, containing different versions of the underlying libraries

:i386 refers to the architecture that the binary is compiled for

---

If you only want to use "header-only" boost libraries, you don't need to install these packages, you can just go to source forge, download the tarball for whatever boost version you want, and point your compiler / build system to include the boost root, without actually building boost.

But, likely, there are other programs on your system that rely on compiled boost, so generically I would suggest to install 'libboost-all-dev'

Comment: What're the differences between `libboost-all-dev` and `libboost-dev`